# Why do I have to create a function to add items to an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I was working through a tutorial and I created a typo that stumped me.  I know how to correct the code but I'm curious to know why wouldn't this code compile when I try to add items to the array unless its done inside a function?  The typo in this code was that it needed to be inside of an init function.  Therefore I'm curious, why can't I add items to an array outside of a function?  Is it because adding items to an array is some type of action and this action wouldn't happen unless it were inside of a function?

```
import Foundation

final class PersistencyManager {

  private var albums = [Album]()


  //dummy list of albums...
  let album1 = Album.init(title: "Best of Bowie", artist: "David Bowie", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_david_bowie_best_of_bowie.png", year: "1992")

  let album2 = Album.init(title: "It's My Life", artist: "No Doubt", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_no_doubt_its_my_life_bathwater.png", year: "2003")

  let album3 = Album.init(title: "Nothing Like The Sun", artist: "Sting", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_sting_nothing_like_the_sun.png", year: "1999")

  let album4 = Album.init(title: "American Pie", artist: "Madonna", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_u2_staring_at_the_sun.png", year: "2000")



  //the line of code shows a compile error that reads "expected declaration"
  albums = [album1, album2, album3, album4]

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function to add items to an array. But you can't just stick code where you want. It needs to be in a proper location such as a function or appropriate code block. The top level of a class is not where runnable code is allowed.

The following reworking of your code would work just fine:

```
final class PersistencyManager {
    private var albums = [
        Album.init(title: "Best of Bowie", artist: "David Bowie", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_david_bowie_best_of_bowie.png", year: "1992"),

        Album.init(title: "It's My Life", artist: "No Doubt", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_no_doubt_its_my_life_bathwater.png", year: "2003"),

        Album.init(title: "Nothing Like The Sun", artist: "Sting", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_sting_nothing_like_the_sun.png", year: "1999"),

        Album.init(title: "American Pie", artist: "Madonna", genre: "Pop", coverUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/CoverProject/album/album_u2_staring_at_the_sun.png", year: "2000")
    ]
}
```

The difference here is this is now just a declaration and an initialization.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that the `init` method can be called implicitly. Just do `Album(` instead of `Album.init(`

Comment: @ColGraff Yes, I actually prefer the shorter syntax. I simply copied and pasted while focusing on the question.

Comment: I figured you did, I commented mostly for anyone who didn't know that fact. One trick I sometimes like doing when creating an `Array` is to declare the type and then use `.init` to shorthand fill it: `let foo: [Bar] = [.init(2), .init(1), .init(5)]` - it can be more compact.

Comment: @rmaddy got it.  The code above where you created a declaration AND an initialization, is this what you meant when referring to an "appropriate code block"?  I'd like to confirm explicitly that this is what you meant.

Comment: @Q.A.Neuro.Tech I meant code blocks such as functions, and property getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are accessing the instance of controller before your `UIViewController` is initialized. and if you putting it inside function you must have to call this method inside another method i.e (`viewDidLoad`). So at that time your viewcontroller is initialized so you can use instance.

If you want to achieve this things you can use `lazy` initialization.